# Characters replaced with angled bracket sequence, possibly due to encoding

Tags: character-encoding, markdown

I have files in Markdown, saved in a Dropbox folder. One of them replaces characters with angled bracket sequences. For example a `git diff no-index` between the saved file and a copy-paste of the text to a new file gives:

```
-# `Package <81><B4>julia-mode-0.3<81><B4> is unavailable.`
+# `Package ´julia-mode-0.3´ is unavailable.`
```

Other sequences are `<91><A1><AD>` for ellipsis (`...`), `<81><A0>` for a space, `<81><E2>` for `â`, `<86><A4>` for the euro sign `€`, `<91><A1><B0>` for opening double quote, `<91><A1><B1>` for closing double quote, `<86><A1>` for opening single quote, `<86><A2>` for closing single quote.

The variable `buffer-file-coding-system` is `emacs-mule-unix` in the original buffer and `utf-8-unix` in the buffer with the copy-pasted content.

Many other files in the same folder have recently stopped showing with proper formatting. They list `Fundamental` in the mode line instead of `Markdown`. The characters display properly. Many of these buffers have a variable `buffer-file-coding-system` of `undecided-unix`.

As I started having these issues around the same time, I believe they are related. Since the characters display fine in Emacs, it's not a question of converting the buffer from one encoding to another (as many of the threads I have found).

How can I save all of these buffers back to `utf8-unix`, and what triggered this behavior?

Comment: Does it happen for files outside of the Dropbox folder? What do you mean exactly by "copy-paste"? How does the files display in the terminal (eg `less myfile`)?  What character set does the `file` command report (`file myfile` in the shell)?

Comment: No, so far it has only happened to files in the Dropbox folder. By "copy-paste" I mean `Cmd-A`, `Cmd-C`, `Cmd-V` on macOS.  `less myfile` shows the same thing: the first file as ```Package <81><B4>julia-mode-0.3<81><B4> is unavailable.``` and the second as ```Package ´julia-mode-0.3´ is unavailable.```. The `file` command reports `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text` for the first and `Lisp/Scheme program text, UTF-8 Unicode text` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. To start with, I doubt that Emacs has replaced a horizontal ellipsis with the string "<91><A1><AD>". Instead, I suspect that what you're seeing is what your shell prints out when it sees a byte sequence that aren't valid in utf-8.

Indeed, `<91><A1><AD>` is not the byte sequence that utf-8 specifies for a HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS character; I would expect to see `<E2><80><A6>`. (But of course, if your shell saw that byte sequence it would have drawn the glyph for the ellipsis as expected.)

It looks like the `emacs-mule-unix` coding system isn't compatible with utf-8 (the documentation on it isn't very specific). I would update the Emacs configuration so that it always saves files in `utf-8-unix` instead.

Comment: I followed [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674481/how-to-configure-gnu-emacs-to-write-unix-or-dos-formatted-files-by-default) to set the defaults to UTF-8, but it still showed the same characters. Do you have a way to save in UTF-8 that avoids copy-pasting?

Comment: Despite setting four coding systems to `'utf-8-unix`, some buffers still save as `‘undecided-unix’`.